# Решение задачки | python

Tags: python

Шахматная ладья ходит по горизонтали или вертикали. Даны две различные клетки шахматной доски, определите, может ли ладья попасть с первой клетки на вторую одним ходом. Программа получает на вход четыре числа от 1 до 8 каждое, задающие номер столбца и номер строки сначала для первой клетки, потом для второй клетки. Программа должна вывести "YES", если из первой клетки ходом ладьи можно попасть во вторую или "NO" в противном случае.

решение:

```
# тут ввод с клавиатуры нужных координат для оси x первой клеточки
x1 = int(input())

# ввод с клавиатуры нужных координат для оси y первой клеточки
y1 = int(input())

# ввод с клавиатуры нужных координат для оси x второй клеточки
x2 = int(input())

# ввод с клавиатуры нужных координат для оси y второй клеточки
y2 = int(input())

# когда ладья ходит, координата по одной из осей не меняется
# (если не понятно, нарисуйте шахматную доску и подпишите координаты клеточек)
if x1 == x2 or y1 == y2:
  print('YES') 
else:
  print('NO')
```

Вопрос вот в чём : я не могу понять как это работает. Вот серьезно,   я нарисовал на листке шахматную доску и подставлял цифры. Вот смотрите: возьмем входные даннные

```
x1 = 2
x2 = 4
y1 = 3        ОТВЕТ: YES
y2 = 4

if x1 == x2 or y1 == y2:
  print('YES')
```

эти цифры никак не равны, каким образом выводится YES?

Comment: Обратите внимание на то, в какой последовательности в коде программы вы спрашиваете числа. Затем - в какой последовательности вы пишете у себя в вопрос из. В коде вы спрашиваете `x1 y1 x2 y2`, однако в своем вопросе вы спрашиваете `x1 x2 y1 y2`.

Answer (score 2):

Ввод идёт в таком порядке: x1,y1,x2,y2, и для данного набора 2,4,3,4 значения y совпадают

Answer (score 0):

Вы просто не в том порядке вписали цифры. И получается что x2 это y1, а y2 это y2 и т.к. y1=4=y2 программа выводит YES